# Missing Property Exception on trigger build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I am getting the following error: `No. Such property: $env for class:  WorkflowSscript`

Here is my implementation:

```
node('test node') {
    stage ('apply terraform') {
    // this stage is passing successfully
        env_meta = getEnvMeta("test", "${env.ENV_NAME}")
    }

    stage ('Run Env Tets'){
        build job: 'infra_tets', parameters: [
            string (name: 'UI_TESTS', value: 'all'),
            string (name: 'env', value: String.valueOf($env.ENV_NAME)),
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
node('test node'){
    stage ('apply terraform') {
    // this stage is passing successfully
        env.env_meta = getEnvMeta("test", "${env.ENV_NAME}")
    }

    stage ('Run Env Tets'){
        build job: 'infra_tets', parameters: [
            string (name: 'UI_TESTS', value: 'all'),
            string (name: 'env', value: env.env_meta),
        ]
    }
}
```

notice that if you use quotes you need to access env var by `"${env.ENV_NAME}"`

Comment: By the way, you can also access it via `env["env_meta"]`